# Google Analytics Page Tracking stopped working

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager, pageviews

my main problem is, that since the 23rd of July the Google Analytics Page Tracking is not working anymore, even though I did not change anything.

I have multiple Websites, which have an integrated questionnaire. If people answer a question, the URL does not change, but somehow (I did not write the questionnaire by myself, therefore I do not know how it is exactly working) Analytics tracked their behaviour as Page-View(with specific URLs e.g. [www.url.com/question-5](http://www.url.com/question-5)).

I think this is the line of code, which tells Google Analytics, that it shall track the Page-View.

```
window._mfq.push(["newPageView", "/".concat(M || t)]),
"function" == typeof window.ga && (window.ga("gtm1.set", "dimension1", e),
window.ga("gtm1.set", "page", "/".concat(M || t)),
window.ga("gtm1.send", "pageview")),
```

Google Analytics is integrated with Google Tag Manager and the Google Analytics Tag is triggered by the build in "Page-view" Trigger.

How is it possible, that it was working with no problems till last week and suddenly it is not anymore (on roughly 10 different Websites). It seems to me, that Google Analytics (or Tag Manager) did an update, but I cannot find any information regarding this.

Do you know, if something has changed in the last week?

Addition:
The Google Analytics Debugger tells me the following:

```
Executing Google Analytics commands.
   >Running command: ga("gtm1.set", "dimension1", 200624)
Executing Google Analytics commands. 
   >Running command: ga("gtm1.set", "page", "/steps-route-1-1-question")
Executing Google Analytics commands.
   >Running command: ga("gtm1.send", "pageview")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem.

The variable gtm1 is not initialized. The page view is therefore no longer sent to GTM. I don't know exactly why that worked before. Possibly. had the gtm variable, which records the actual page view, the name gtm1 and due to some change on the part of Google this is no longer the case.

Comment: ouh thanks, I did not realize, that I answered my english question in german...

Comment: @MoSc I edited your answer and replaced the german text with the english translation. Please do this yourself if this happens again, answers that aren't written in english will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Yup this was a Google change. Events are now send using gtag function, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events